# Как в Android проложить маршрут в MapView Яндекс карт?

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandexmapkit

Возможно ли в Android проложить маршрут на Яндекс Картах без использования Intent и вызова Яндекс приложения? И если да, то каким образом?

Должно получиться что-то вроде этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @pavlofff я понимаю, я имею ввиду, возможно ли средствами Android Studio создать View элемент в приложении, на котором будет отображаться Яндекс карта, и на ней - маршрут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В мобильных приложениях можно использовать API Яндекс.Карт через webView.

[Пример использования API Карт в Android приложении](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/59234?from=SO)

[Пример построения маршрута](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_driving?from=SO)

Comment: Да, но тогда вместе с Яндекс.картами приходит ещё поле ввода "Поиск мест на карте", и иногда - реклама, а этого не должно быть в приложении, только одна карта, метки и проложенный маршрут

Comment: API, конечно же, позволяет настроить всё, что будет или не будет отображаться на карте. Можно сделать карту с маршрутом и вообще без кнопок, например, так: https://jsfiddle.net/qdhmown0/. 

Реклама отображается только в результатах поиска - не будете использовать поиск, не будет рекламы.

Comment: тот пример, который Вы мне отправили - на javascript, мне нужно сделать карту в мобильном приложении через Android Studio

Comment: На сегодняшний день единственный способ добавить Яндекс.Карты в мобильное приложение - использовать JavaScript API в webView, как написано в исходном ответе.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я сначала не понял, как использовать javascript, но когда попробовал - всё получилось.
Подскажите ещё, если не трудно, как задавать координаты динамически. Допустим у меня логистическое приложение, и имеются адреса с координатами. А так как карта использует html файл, как мне передавать программно туда координаты?

Comment: Лучше задать про это отдельный вопрос. Также обратите внимание, что для логистических задач, например, мониторинга транспорта в реальном времени допустимо использовать только коммерческую версию API.

Comment: Да нет, не мониторинг транспорта, а маршрут для водителя: у него есть 3 точки, и приложение выстраивает ему маршрут

Comment: Тогда это закрытая система и тоже попадает под ограничения бесплатной версии. Нужна коммерческая https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/commercial/

Comment: понятно) спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю жесткого условия, что должны быть именно яндекс карты не стоит.

Можно воспользоваться google maps. У них отличная [документация](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start?hl=ru), хорошо расписанная и с примерами.
Конкретно ваш случай есть [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/244229/).

Comment: Установил Google Карты. Всё указал в манифесте, build.gradle, ключи для debug и release, запускаю приложение - карта не показывает. И в логе никаких ошибок, просто карта пустая. Пошарился по форумам - никаких дельных советов

Comment: @ПавелСумароков на какой версии тестишь? Интернет включить не забыл? В нижнем левом углу значок google есть?

Comment: Android 3.0. Wi-Fi постоянно включен. Значок google есть в нижнем левом углу, и это единственное, что отображается на view-элементе

Comment: @ПавелСумароков получи заново ключ, и удоставерься что там нет проеблов , если не поможет попробуй версию повыше

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но всё таки пример с Яндекс Картами удалось реализовать быстрее и проще)